# Python script does not start again properly after closing it

Tags: php, python, html, apache, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a robot which I can control myself through a website.
I have coded a Python script which lets the robot drive in a (more or less) straight line. Activating the script through the website was no problem but the problems appear when I try to stop it and restart it. 
 
When I click the stop button it does this in a php file:

```
exec("sh /home/pi/Maxwheel/ScriptePython/geradeaus/kill.sh");
exec("sudo python /home/pi/Maxwheel/ScriptePython/geradeaus/stopp.py");
```

kill.sh will execute this command to kill the python script:

```
sudo pkill -f vorne.py
```

stopp.py will clean the pins up *again*. I am already doing this at the end of the Python script but I have experienced when I simply kill the script the robot will still drive forward. I figured that killing the script will not trigger the `GPIO.cleanup()` At the end of my Python script. Yes the Python Script is being stopped / killed (checked with `ps aux | grep python`)
The robot then comes to a stop. But when I try to start the script again through a button, the robot does not start properly. It will try to drive but only for a second and then comes to a stop. After that I have to push it and then it will drive again for like a second. This does not make sense to me because the Python script is in a loop so the robot should never stop. Even when I try to start the script manually it won't work.
This is the code from "stopp.py". I just setup all the Pins again like I did it in the Python Script and clean them up right after that.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't provide the actual python code in stopp.py

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: This seems to be a quite messy design with php for web page, one python script for start, sh for killing the script, and another python script to clean up GPIO. Why not just use pure python to create the website as well controlling the GPIO like [this one](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/). You didn't show the php and vrone.py, it is kind of hard to figure out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you may not be seeing the error, I would try this instead.  It could be that your code is not getting to the cleanup phase.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
try:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
except Exception as exc:
    print('Error : {}'.format(str(exc)))
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```